# Find variance of random vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, machine-learning

I have a question about random vectors

A random vector (X, Y ) has a continuous distribution with a density function
$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}c · x &\mbox{for}& 0 ≤ x ≤ 2, \max(0, 1 − x) ≤ y ≤ 2 − x\\[1ex] 0 &&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
c > 0 is a constant. Find variance of a Y conditioned on X = 1.5,
Var(Y |X = 1.5).

Thank you,

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: First , determine $c$.

Comment: I need to integrate c*x  first for dx and then dy, with the given boundries. But I didnt understand how can I convert max(0,1−x)≤y≤2−x

Comment: Wait.  If the support for $X$ is $[0..2]$, then conditioning on $X=2.5$ makes no sense.  Please check that condition.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right it should be 1.5

Comment: Good.  Meanwhile you can partition the support based on the maximum function. $${\{ 0\leq x\leq 2, \max\{0,1-x\}\leq y\leq 2-x\}\\=\{0\leq x\lt 1,1-x\leq y\leq 2-x\}\cup\{1\leq x\leq 2,0\leq y\leq 2-x\}}$$

Comment: The bounds are right there.$$1=\int_0^1\int_{1-x}^{2-x} cx\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^2\int_{0}^{2-x} cx\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm dx$$ Similarly:$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}\int_{1-x}^{2-x} cx\,\mathrm d y&:&0\leq x\lt 1\\\int_{0}^{2-x} cx\,\mathrm d y&:&1\leq x\leq 2\\0&:&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ok I understand. Now I can solve the question. Thank you so much for your help.